# Is it possible to add bold and Italic in one line is css?

Tags: css

Currently I saw you can do something like:

```
body{
font-weight:bold;
font-style:italic;
}
```

Is there a way to do...

```
body{
font: bold italic???
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, via the [CSS shorthand font rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font).

> Formal syntax: [ [ <‘font-style’> ||  ||
>   <‘font-weight’> || <‘font-stretch’> ]? <‘font-size’> [ /
>   <‘line-height’> ]? <‘font-family’> ] | caption | icon | menu |
>   message-box | small-caption | status-bar

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand

Some examples:

```
p { font: 12px/14px sans-serif }
p { font: 80% sans-serif }
p { font: x-large/110% "New Century Schoolbook", serif }
p { font: bold italic large Palatino, serif }
p { font: normal small-caps 120%/120% fantasy }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, just like you said, using [`font`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand):

```
p { font: bold italic large Palatino, serif }
```

From the docs:

> The `font` property is, except as described below, a shorthand property for setting `font-style`, `font-variant`, `font-weight`, `font-size`, `line-height` and `font-family` at the same place in the style sheet.